# How to get sub .each() elements in jQuery .each() to build a Table of Contents

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to dynamically build a "table of contents" from H2 & H3 elements on a page.
Currently I am using this code which gets all the H2 tags and builds an anchor menu.
This works.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="block_1" class="parent_div_class">
    
    <h2 class="h2_class">Heading 1</h2>
    
    <div id="block_1a" class="child_div_class">
        <h3 class="h3_class">Sub Heading 1a</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block_1b" class="child_div_class">
        <h3 class="h3_class">Sub Heading 1b</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div id="block_2" class="parent_div_class">
    
    <h2 class="h2_class">Heading 2</h2>
    
    <div id="block_2a" class="child_div_class">
        <h3 class="h3_class">Sub Heading 2a</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block_2b" class="child_div_class">
        <h3 class="h3_class">Sub Heading 2b</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    
</div>

<nav id="table_of_contents">
    <ul></ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.parent_div_class').each(function(i, obj) {
    var title = $(this).find('h2.h2_class').html();
    var anchor = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#table_of_contents ul').append('<li><a href="#' + anchor + '">' + title + '</a></li>');
});
```

**Output:**
*This is working fine*

```
<nav id="table_of_contents">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#block_1">Heading 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#block_2">Heading 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Question:**

How do I also include the H3 tags? Am needing to use `.each()` within a `.each()`?

**Desired Output:**

```
<nav id="table_of_contents">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#block_1">Heading 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#block_1a">Sub Heading 1a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#block_1b">Sub Heading 1b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#block_2">Heading 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#block_2a">Sub Heading 2a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#block_2b">Sub Heading 2b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up editing this plugin to achieve what I was needing:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/table-of-contents-contentify.html